# How to use vue router and vuex inside custom element from root?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router, vuejs3

I have project with nested [custom elements](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/web-components.html#definecustomelement). Now I need to vuex & vue router. How I can use this packages from root custom element and then use in all child custom elements?

Currently I tried only use vuex inside each component like this:

```
<script>
import store from './store';

export default {
  setup() {
    const state = store.state;

    return { state };
  },
};
</script>
```

Here is [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-custom-elements-hxuwvh) project with nested custom elements

Here is my `main.js` file code:

```
import { defineCustomElement } from "./defineCustomElementWithStyles";
import App from "./App.ce.vue";

customElements.define("app-root", defineCustomElement(App));
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Vue plugins require the app instance, which is not defined for components created from `defineCustomElement()`. As a workaround, you can install the plugins on a temporary app instance, and then copy the resulting context over to the actual app, as seen in this utility (which we'll use later):

```js
// defineCustomElementWithStyles.js
import { defineCustomElement as VueDefineCustomElement, h, createApp, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'

export const defineCustomElement = (component, { plugins = [] } = {}) =>
  VueDefineCustomElement({
    render: () => h(component),
    setup() {
      const app = createApp()

      // install plugins
      plugins.forEach(app.use)

      const inst = getCurrentInstance()
      Object.assign(inst.appContext, app._context)
      Object.assign(inst.provides, app._context.provides)
    },
  })
```

Use the `defineCustomElement()` above instead of the one from `vue`:

```js
// main.js
import { defineCustomElement } from './defineCustomElementWithStyles'
import App from './App.ce.vue'
import store from './store'
import router from './router'

customElements.define(
  'app-root',
  defineCustomElement(App, {
    plugins: [store, router],
  })
)
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-custom-elements-with-plugins?file=src/defineCustomElementWithStyles.js)

Comment: Has someone managed to type hint this properly with TS? I'm currently struggling with this.

Comment: same here, besides that it works fine. @acme, did you make it work?

Comment: How about using Vuetify? Is it possible to use vuetify inside a custom web component?

Comment: I've included vuetify as you explained, but the custom theme of vuetify, does not implement on vuetify components!

Comment: @amirtbi That's because [Vuetify attaches styles directly to the root document instead of using Vue's style support](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/7622#issuecomment-504373568). You can try the workarounds in the linked issue.

Comment: @tony19,Could you please take a look the link of question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76936901/7926619

Comment: Hi @tony19 a not here, this doesn't work if you have slots for custom elements

Answer (score 6):

Just a little fix for tony19's solution:

```
export const defineCustomElementWrapped = (component, { plugins = [] } = {}) =>
  defineCustomElement({
    styles: component.styles, // <- this
    render: () => h(component),
    setup() {
      const app = createApp()

      // install plugins
      plugins.forEach(app.use)

      const inst = getCurrentInstance()
      Object.assign(inst.appContext, app._context)
      Object.assign(inst.provides, app._context.provides)
    },
  })
```

and then

```
customElements.define(
  'app-root',
  defineCustomElementWrapped(App, {
    plugins: [store, router],
  })
)
```

This will also include styles exported by components

(also I don't like shadowing original function names if you are changing their behaviors, so I renamed it)

Might be also required:

```
    styles: component.styles.map((style) => {
      return style
        .replace(":root", ":host") // <- rename :root values to :host
        .replace("body {", "#my-app {"); // <- in case of frameworks like bootstrap that styles directly body
    }),
```

Comment: I like your answer. To get it work, I had to import the entiry vue im my web component-<styles>. Yet I am struggeling to strip away all unnessary CSS from styles. do you have any idea to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Just a small adjustments to the great answers: when you need props, emits or styles, it might be easier to destructure the component instead of wrapping it:

```
const defineCustomElement = (component, { plugins = [] } = {}) =>
  VueDefineCustomElement({
    ...component, // <---- use all props from the original component (except setup)
    setup(...args) {
      const app = createApp({})
      plugins.forEach(app.use)
      const instance = getCurrentInstance()
      Object.assign(instance.appContext, app._context)
      Object.assign(instance.provides, app._context.provides)

      return component.setup?.(...args) // <---- run initial setup if exists
    },
  })
```