# Vue - using props on custom elements fails using createApp and mount?

Tags: vuejs3, web-component

We would like to pass props to custom elements that uses createApp

```
// index.html
<div id="my-root">    
   <my-element prop1="abc"></my-element>
</div>
```

```
// my-element.vue
<script lang="ts" setup>
const props = defineProps<{ prop1: number }>();
</script>

<template>
    {{props.prop1}}
</template>
```

This works fine, but as our custome element get bigger we would like to register components and use e.g pinia and other tools. Do use those we need to add createApp and mount it. But then prop1 is always undefined

```
// main.ts
import ...<lots of imports>
import AppCe from "./AppWebComponent.ce.vue";
import { createPinia } from "pinia";

// Adding code below is causing prop1 to be undefined - if we skip this part, prop1 works fine
const pinia = createPinia();
const app = createApp(App);
app.use(pinia).use(ConfirmDialog);
app.component(...<lots of components>);
app.mount("#my-root");

const ceApp = defineCustomElement(AppCe);
customElements.define("my-element", ceApp);
```

**update:**
Here's a sample without: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-script-setup-with-vite-56rizn?file=src/my-element/my-element-main.js

And here's a sample with the createApp: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-script-setup-with-vite-gtkbaq?file=index.html

Any idea on how we could solve this?
We have a fallback, that is to do a getElementById and read the attribute value in the mounted callback - but that is not an optimal solution.

Thanks for any ideas!

**update2:**
Here's an attempt using @duannex suggestion. We're getting closer, the app is availible, components registered, but still no sigar. : https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-script-setup-with-vite-ofwcjt?file=src/my-element/defineCustomElementWrapped.js

Comment: Could you reproduce your problem on https://stackblitz.com/?

Comment: @Duannx thanks for looking into this. I just updated the question with two samples

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69808113/how-to-use-vue-router-and-vuex-inside-custom-element-from-root) can help

Comment: When defining custom elements (a.k.a Web components) - you should not mount them as a regular Vue application. Web components (after their registration) become just normal HTML tags - so you must use them just as you use other HTML tags. If you mount a Vue application onto any HTML element (custom or not) - then this element will be entirely replaced by the generated Vue instance and therefore you will lose the HTML attributes that were present in the original HTML for the given element.

Comment: @Duannx thanks again, we're getting closer. I updated with a new sample.

Comment: @IVOGELOV thanks for commenting. Yes, I understand that mounting is not a good idea. What do you think of the update2 approach?

Comment: This is the working version of your example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-script-setup-with-vite-deztqr?file=src/my-element/MyCustomElement.ce.vue

Comment: @IVOGELOV thanks for suggesting a solution, but your attempt does not solve the core problem, that is to get a reference to the app. I need access to the app like this `app.use(pinia).use(ConfirmDialog);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on **update2** with the wrapped `defineCustomElement`; Just pass the props to the render function:

```
    render() {
      return h(component, this.$props)
    },
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-script-setup-with-vite-vfdnvg?file=src/my-element/defineCustomElementWrapped.js