# How can Add libraries like Vuetify inside of a web component created by Vue 3?

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, web-component

I am looking for to add some libraries like Vuetify or use other Javascript libraries inside of a web component created by Vue3 in [vue-web-component](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/amirtbi/vue-webcomponent/main?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000h2v6k7gaotu9m%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B53.069620253164565%252C46.930379746835435%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000c2v6kda83dl25%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000g2v6kbiwqb3gr%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000e2v6kqi2h8yap%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cll6898v2000c2v6kda83dl25%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000c2v6kda83dl25%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clligjv9s00hu2v6amwg4uj1i%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000b2v6k0y58lmu0%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.vue%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll689y8r01522v6kh96kosrj%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Findex.html%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clligjv9s00hu2v6amwg4uj1i%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522SAVING%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fweb-component.ts%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clligm5pk02m92v6ar3spskd0%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522temporary%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522cll6898v2000e2v6kqi2h8yap%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000e2v6kqi2h8yap%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cll689dl000xt2v6kz62u22p1%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll689dl000xt2v6kz62u22p1%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522cll6898v2000g2v6kbiwqb3gr%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000g2v6kbiwqb3gr%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cllignuq003le2v6aywhxouw9%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll6898v2000f2v6kif7dz18o%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522cll6899230004d8i33k6i8xxk%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cll689anb00jw2v6k0nd911ux%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522build%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clligmnb602sq2v6ajyjrzo2h%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522comment%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cllignuq003le2v6aywhxouw9%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use vue router and vuex inside custom element from root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69808113/how-to-use-vue-router-and-vuex-inside-custom-element-from-root)

Comment: No, this is not my question, i tried this apporach for vuetify, but it does not work.!

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using the `defineCustomElement` override explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69820280/4883195):

```
const component = {
  template: `
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
    <v-app>
      ...
    </v-app>
  `
}
const vuetify = createVuetify({})
const customVuetifyElement = defineCustomElement(component, {plugins: [vuetify]})
customElements.define('custom-vuetify-element', customVuetifyElement)
```

I had to include the Vuetify CSS both in the custom component and the outside page. Icon fonts had to be included in the outside page. Not sure why.

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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).

Comment: Thanks, Could you please take a look at the https://codesandbox.io/p/github/amirtbi/vue-webcomponent/main?workspaceId=d37dd2f5-9fbc-4611-a576-2bf4117c74d0. How can implement your approach inside of the component?

Comment: I am looking for  including vuetify for source of :https://codesandbox.io/p/github/amirtbi/vue-webcomponent/main?workspaceId=d37dd2f5-9fbc-4611-a576-2bf4117c74d0. Is it  viable to implement it with your approach for coin-tracker.ce.vue?

Comment: The sandbox does not open due to permission error, my guess is that the repository is private? One way or another, I am not familiar with coin-tracker.ce.vue, so I couldn't tell you

Comment: I added the shared link to main question, The main problem is how to include the vuetify inside of the project. The SFC approach is used for creating web component.

Comment: The link in the question gives me a "Project not found" error.

Comment: I updated the link of project, I have solved the vuetify usage inside of the custom web component. The new question about vue web component is accessible through the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76936901/how-can-add-custom-theme-of-vuetify-library-inside-of-a-web-component